# How to chunk an object into smaller objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The goal is to break an object of unknown length and shape into small objects 3 elements each. Only vanilla JS solution; I don't want to use _.pick etc.

Example of large object:

```
const data = {
    someFirstKey: 'someFirstVal',
    someSecondKey: 'someSecondVal',
    ...
    someLastKey: 'someLastVal'
}
```

Desired chunk with 3 keys:

```
{someKey0: 'someVal0', someKey1: 'someVal1', someKey2, 'someVal2'}
```

Comment: Consider providing your attempts or research, if any, to prevent your question from being downvoted and/or closed. Additionally as Paulpro points out, while recent versions of JS may be more adherent to ordered object keys, they are still not safe to depend on. If you want ordered key/value pairs, consider using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

Comment: so read the keys and slice off the range.... just remember that objects do not have order so might not be what you think it should be.

Comment: @Paulpro, to be precise data is being recieved from servers. I only substituted it with a plain JS object.  The order doesn't matter, so I just need a pairs of 3 elems of data. [0-2], [3-5], [6-8] and so on.

Comment: @VonAxt If the order of the items being returned is important, then the data should not be formatted as an object, but rather an array. If you always want the keys to be sorted alphabetically as in your example, that makes things easier - you can pull out the keys, sort them, and get their values in order.

Comment: You could also define `const visibleCols = ['a', 'b', 'c'];` and work with that instead of a range.

Comment: I can't access by key name, only key position.

Comment: @VonAxt Object keys do not have positions.

Comment: @TylerRoper I ment Object.keys(data)[0], Object.keys(data)[1] etc.

Comment: So wait, your goal is to break an object up into several smaller objects, but you don't care how it gets broken up as long as each small object has at most 3 keys?

Comment: @Paulpro exactly. break an object of unknown length and shape into small objects 3 elements each.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  I can't imagine any valid business case for breaking an arbitrary data structure into smaller arbitrary data structures without knowing how they fit together or can get deserialized reliably.

Comment: @Paul, imagine a gallery of userTours implemented with hopscotch. Only 3 columns might be visible because of the amount of tours (which BTW are written as a JS object). So What I can do is to show only few of a unknown amount. And let users navigate to next or prev columns of tours.

Comment: @VonAxt I agree w/ everyone else, this is a far better case for an array than an object.  But see my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the comments, it seems like you are actually looking for a way to split an object up into several smaller objects. I would approach that like this:

```js
const data = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7};

const chunk_size = 3, chunks = [];
for ( const cols = Object.entries( data ); cols.length; )
  chunks.push( cols.splice(0, chunk_size).reduce( (o,[k,v])=>(o[k]=v,o), {}));

console.log( chunks );
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this might not be the most efficient way, but it works on my box. ;)

```
const data = {} // fill in your data here
const keys = Object.keys(data); // gets you the keys from your obj. 
const numberOfWholeParts = Math.floor( keys.length / 3 );  // or whatever your size limit is
const remainder = keys.length % 2; // keys left after all whole parts are filled

const arrayOfParts = [];

for(let i=0;i<numberOfWholeParts;i++) {
   const obj = {};
   const keySegment = keys.slice(i*3, i*3+3);

   for(let j=0; j<3; j++) {
     obj[keySegment[j]] = data[keySegment[j]];
   }
   arrayOfParts.push(obj);
} 
if(remainder > 0){
  const obj = {};
  let remainingKeys = keys.slice(-remainder)
  for(let i=0; i<remainingKeys.length;i++) {
    obj[remainingKeys[i]] = data[remainingKeys[i]];
  }
  arrayOfParts.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const entries = Object.entries(data);
const grouped = [];

for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    if (i % groupSize === 0) {
        grouped.push([entries[i]]);
    } else {
        grouped[Math.floor(i / groupSize)].push(entries[i]);
    }
}

const chunks = grouped.map(o => Object.fromEntries(o));
```

Answer (score 1):

For the readers who would come here not necessarily in search of vanilla solution, but who would be happy with more expressive (even if slower) solutions, such a solution with Lodash would be

```js
_.map(_.chunk(_.toPairs(obj), 3), _.fromPairs)
```

```js
// input
obj = { k1: 'v1', k2: 'v2', k3: 'v3', k4: 'v4', k5: 'v5', k6: 'v6', k7: 'v7', k8: 'v8' };

// magic
res = _.map(_.chunk(_.toPairs(obj), 3), _.fromPairs)

// print
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Object destructuring

```
const { someKey0, someKey1, someKey2 } = data

const newData = {
    someKey0,
    someKey1,
    someKey2
}
```